# What's the difference between "content menu links" and "menu links"?

Tags: features

I am using [Features](https://drupal.org/project/features) module to export menus and related links. In my Drupal installation I have both "content menu links" and "menu links" available to insert in a feature. What is the difference? They seem to work both.

Comment: Are you using any menu related modules ? Because out the of the box drupal i see only Menu Links... Can you give more insight into your problem ?